# Execute conditional on a specific set/list of hosts ansible

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible

I'm using ansible the first time and have a task to change a property only for production env.
I quickly read on the internet but haven't been able to fully understand the concept.

[image]

This is what my dir hierarchy looks like. So basically the file is neither task/role/handler as there's no name/task/handler/role tag/key in the main.yaml file just kafka server broker properties and other coinfg variables. And on the in the docs/examples I see these days and then when and host keys/tags to do this action.

I want to do something like

disable/set false the kafka topic deletion for production env. by default this property is true.
delete.topic.enable: true

I have something like.

```
{% set env_bool: ture if ("production" == {{inventory_dir.split('/')[-1]}}) else false %}
  delete.topic.enable: true
```

I have three env dirs, and in production/inventory, I have IPs for kafka instances in the cluster.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you need to learn a lot more about ansible before being able to understand the answer to your question. Espc. read on what roles are and how they are structured. The file `defaults/main.yml` does not contain any tasks, but only variable defaults. Tasks are stored in `tasks/main.yml`. When you want to override a var in `defaults`, you set it in your inventory for that host or group, you do not change the role.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have a templated if condition, always define the variable

So, in `defaults/main.yml` set the property to true, then in the inventory file or in a `group_vars` directory, add a group variable for production that overrides it

Then, in the property file template, you can simply refer `delete.topic.enable={{ delete_topic_enabled }}`

By the way, you might want to look at the existing Confluent Ansible scripts